# Attaching to the correct process but unable to debug - No symbols have loaded error - VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug a web application hosted in local IIS web server. I have attached the VS debugger to the process but get the error - "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for the document".

I have done the following things:

- Deleted the bin/obj folders
- Cleaned and rebuilt the solution
- Closed and reopened the solution

Things I noticed:

- Opened Process Explorer and made sure I am attaching to the correct process.
- Opened Debug-Windows-Modules but cannot find the project dlls and referenced dlls (Does this notify that the right process is not attached?)

Please share your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: try running vs as the local admin. or, check the checkbox that says "show all processes from all users" or something like that. then         look for the correct `w3wp.exe` process ...

Comment: @Xander: Yes, I am already running vs as Admin and attaching to the correct process. Also, verified in Process Explorer explorer that I am attaching to the correct process.

Answer (score 0):

This error will also show up if you have attached to a process that was compiled in release mode.